# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: vb.net, serialization, datatable, dataset

So I created an object called Report. A Report object has several different properties, including a DataSet.  This DataSet is supposed to contain at least one DataTable.  Report is serializable.  In a Unit Test I instantiate a Report object, give its properties values, then serialize it, then deserialize it.

After adding a method to populate the DataSet, the Deserialization function gives me Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
Shouldn't it be getting serialized as a DataSet...not a DataTable? I'm not sure exactly what is causing me this error.  Code snippets are below.  Any help is appreciated!

```
<Serializable> Public Class Report

    Private titleStr As String
    Private startDateTime As DateTime
    Private endDateTime As DateTime
    Private numIntervalsShort As Short
    Private binnedDataSet As DataSet

...property gets and sets...namely:

    Property BinnedData As DataSet
        Get
            Return binnedDataSet
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataSet)
            binnedDataSet = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class


<TestClass()> Public Class ReportObjectTest

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub TestCreateReport()

        Dim testReport As New Project.Report

        testReport.Title = "Test Title"
        testReport.StartDate = "1/1/2015 1:00 AM"
        testReport.EndDate = "1/2/2015 6:00 PM"
        testReport.NumIntervals = 41
        PopulateDataSet(testReport)

        Serialize(testReport)
        Deserialize()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateDataSet(ByRef report As Project.Report)

        report.BinnedData = New DataSet()

        Dim DT1 As DataTable = New DataTable("Test Table1")
        report.BinnedData.Tables.Add(DT1)

        DT1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(Int32)))
        DT1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(Int32)))
        DT1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(Int32)))

        Dim Row1 As DataRow = DT1.NewRow()
        Dim Row2 As DataRow = DT1.NewRow()
        Dim Row3 As DataRow = DT1.NewRow()

        Row1("Column1") = 32
        Row1("Column2") = 15
        Row1("Column3") = 9

        Row2("Column1") = 3
        Row2("Column2") = 27
        Row2("Column3") = 98

        Row2("Column1") = 1
        Row2("Column2") = 12
        Row2("Column3") = 65

    End Sub

    Private Sub Serialize(ByRef report As Project.Report)

        Dim stream As New FileStream("TestReport.xxx", FileMode.Create)
        Dim mySerializer As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()

        Try
            mySerializer.Serialize(stream, report)
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Error saving the report. " & ex.Message)
            Throw
        Finally
            stream.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Deserialize()

        Dim readTestReport As New Project.Report()

        Dim stream As New FileStream("TestReport.xxx", FileMode.Open)
        Dim myDeserializer As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()

        Try
            readTestReport = DirectCast(myDeserializer.Deserialize(stream), Project.Report)
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening the report. " & ex.Message)
            Throw
        Finally
            stream.Close()
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine & "Values after Deserialization:")
        Console.WriteLine("Title = " & readTestReport.Title)
        Console.WriteLine("Start Date = " & readTestReport.StartDate)
        Console.WriteLine("End Date = " & readTestReport.EndDate)
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Intervals = " & readTestReport.NumIntervals)

        For Each Table In readTestReport.BinnedData.Tables
            For Each Row In Table
                Console.WriteLine("Table Row = " & Row.ToString)
                For Each DataColumn In Row
                    Console.WriteLine(DataColumn.ToString)
                Next
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Should it not be For Each Row In Table.Rows?

Comment: You also need to add the rows to the datatable in the PopulateDataSet function. Just because you create them with NewRow() does not add them to the table. eg. DT1.Rows.Add(Row1) etc...

Comment: Oh yes, I suppose adding the rows would help...thank you!  I also just realized I failed to change "Row2" to "Row3" for setting the values for the third row.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right...figured it out.  The issue lay in how I was trying to display the values of the table after deserializing.  DataTables and DataRows are not enumerable, but the way I was trying to display it was by looping through the way you only can with an enumerable type.

I modified that block to assign the table to a View instead:

```
    Dim tableView As DataView = New DataView(readTestReport.BinnedData.Tables(0))
    Console.WriteLine("Table = ")
    Dim rowView As DataRowView
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each rowView In tableView
        For i = 0 To tableView.Table.Columns.Count - 1
            Console.Write(rowView(i) & vbTab)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

These articles helped:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23a0aths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1